# Send parameters in headers with ActionCable in React Native

Tags: react-native, authentication, header, chat, actioncable

Im stuck trying to create a cable and channel for a chat. Im working in react native and I am consuming a back end made in Ruby on Rails that is expecting my uid in header parameter:

```
def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
  User.find_by(uid: request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) || reject_unauthorized_connection
end
```

What is happening is thay I get stuck in the reject unauthorized connection.

What i'm trying to figure out is how I can send in react native my headers when I create the cable.

I've googled and look here and most answers say is not possible, but they are from 2016 or 2017 so maybe now it is possible?  I see solutions by putting parameters in url as queryparams but in that case I need to change my backend api, so I was wondering if there is another solution without having to change backend.

I'm using **ActionCable from 'actioncable'**.

I've tryied using **ActionCableJwt from 'react-native-action-cable-jwt'** but either I'm doing something wrong or it doesn't help in my case.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Show some action cable code:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import ActionCable from 'actioncable';

import { ANDROID, IOS } from 'constants/common';

ActionCable.getConfig = () => null;

ActionCable.createWebSocketURL = url => url.replace(/^http/, 'ws');

const oldOpen = ActionCable.Connection.prototype.open;
ActionCable.Connection.prototype.open = function open() {
  const result = oldOpen.apply(this);
  this.webSocket.protocol = 'actioncable-v1-json';
  return result;
};

if (Platform.OS === IOS || Platform.OS === ANDROID) {
  global.document = {
    addEventListener() {},
    removeEventListener() {},
  };
}

export default ActionCable;
```

And when I use it (right now with query params instead of headers):

```
  import actionCable from './actionCable';
  import { applyQueryParams } from 'utils/helpers';

  let cable = null;

  return store => next => action => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case createConsumer.toString(): {
        cable?.disconnect();
        const { uid } = action.payload;
        const queryParams = {
          uid,
        };

        cable = actionCable.createConsumer(
          applyQueryParams(Config.CABLE_URL, queryParams),
        );
```

Comment: share your RN side of code for actioncable

Comment: Hi!  Sorry it's been complicated weeks. I ended up just changing backend and accepting the user info in URL query params instead of using headers or cookies. Im still interested in knowing if it would have been possible to do it this way, with headers.